# HTML & JavaScript - Responsive navbar not pushing content down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JavaScript function that triggers a menu-button to open a responsive navbar when the page-width is less than 500px. However when the navbar is triggered to open, the navbar covers the content below it on the page.

Is there a way that I can force content in div ID="content" (code shown below) to be pushed down by the height of the navbar when opened, and pushed back up into the normal position when navbar is closed?

```js
menuButton.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  topNav.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  #menuButton {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menuButton">&#8801;</div>
<nav id="topNav">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="team.html">The Team</a>
  <a href="fixtures.html">Fixtures & Results</a>
  <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
</nav>
<div id="content">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in pure js or a combination of js and css. Here is a pure js example:

```
// select your content layer
const content = document.getElementById('content');

menuButton.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  topNav.classList.toggle('open');
  // if menu is open
  if (topNav.classList.contains('open')) {
      // get the dimensions of the topNav
      const bbox = topNav.getBoundingClientRect();
      const height = bbox.height;
      const top = bbox.top;
      // calculate the new position of the content
      const positionTop = height+top;
      // update the style of the content layer to reflect the change
      contentLayer.style.position = 'absolute';
      contentLayer.style.top = positionTop;
  }
  else {
      contentLayer.style.position = 'relative';
      contentLayer.style.top = 0;
  }
});
```